# How can I delete a Facebook app that I developed?

Tags: facebook

How can I delete a Facebook app that I developed? I don't see a delete button in my Developer Account console.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

**UPDATE 9th June, 2016**

- Navigate to [facebook developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
- Select the application to which you'd like to make changes to
- Navigate to `Settings`->`Advanced` on the left panel.
- In the bottom left of the screen you will find `Delete App`

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! It would be easier if they had put a 'delete' near the save or the edit.

Comment: For sure but I think they don't want you to remove the app "so easy".

Comment: Thanks, I had to google to know how to delete app in Facebook (and found this post). Facebook's ugly UI.

Comment: Note that you need to remove all roles (developers for e.g.), else the Delete button will not appear.

Answer (score 18):

Navigate to the [developer application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), select the application, and click the edit button:
[image]

Then, on the left side of the page, there is a link you can click to delete your application:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to deleting the app is to place it in sandbox mode. This will preserve your application id and keys and save you time in the future.

Just click on Settings>Basic then set "Sandbox Mode" to Enabled.

Comment: I like this option, now it isn't in the Settings tab any more, you'll find this opion in the "Status and Review" tab

Answer (score 2):

Go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

[image: FB Developers - App Page]

Click on the 'Delete App'.
Give your password. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the option is to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

In the page above, developers can hover on one application, there is an arrow which points downward on the top right conner of the app card. Click that arrow and then either `resign` or `delete` the application depend on which are the current roles of the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can put it back into the sandbox mode - which isn't so easy to find either (it's in the App Review section), so I put a current location screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps mentioned before but for some reason when clicking on the app it will take you to the analytics page.

To go to the actual app page from your [apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) you can click on the bell and then `Setting` -> `Advanced` -> `Remove App` at the bottom, or faster, click on the three dots and then `Remove App`

[image]