# did phone verification but facebook did not give our AppId

Tags: facebook, app-id

We need to use the Facebook Javascript SDK.

We followed the instructions to get an 'AppId' for our website:

1) logged in to a working Facebook account

2) looked here to find how to get an app id => http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

3) near the top 1/5 of the page it said:  "The JavaScript SDK requires that you **register your website** with Facebook to get an App ID (or appId)."

4)  I clicked on that '**register your website**' link

5) I clicked on the 'Go to App' button on that page and it took us here: 
    =">https://developers.facebook.com/apps#*=*

6) clicked on the '+Create New App' button

7) it prompted us to enter a name and we entered our website name without the .com

8) it prompted to do a 'phone verification' which we did

9) it said "Verification successful" when we entered the code it text'd to our phone

10)  THEN NOTHING -- no AppId.

How do we find out our AppId?   Our verification was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the procedure you followed is correct.

After navigating to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps#=`, you should see something like this

[image]

Select the application you want in the left column and you will see the details and the top most in the `Summary` section is App ID/API Key

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually after the phone verification -- there was no app-id and entering https://developers.facebook.com/apps -- there was nothing on the left with our app at all.  Here's what happened- we did +Create New App and got shoved into doing a phone verification -- we had never added any apps on the Facebook account before.  After the phone verification succeeded, we thought 'Surely the +Create New App is finished now -- after all, we did +Create New App, typed in our app name, did the verification - where's the app ?!!  I know it must be there somewhere -- FB said 'verification successful'

Comment: now that you dont have to verify again, why don't you try creating an app and see it if gets listed on the left

Comment: So you're saying -- go through the +Create New App process again?  But we already typed in our website name the first time around -- surely Facebook is not going to allow us to create a 2nd app with the same name -- is there a way to delete that first app we created?

Comment: please check this for deleting an app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962072/how-can-i-delete-an-facebook-app-that-i-developed/9962090#9962090

Comment: I read the post; we don't see that'Edit' button at all, only +Create New App.  There's a bug the first time you +Create New App on Facebook -- it checks to make sure you're 'phone verified' and if you aren't -- it shitcans the app name and app creation you already started and switches task to phone verification.   We surmised that bug because, on faith, we added the app all over again using our exact same procedure above -- this time it didn't do the phone verify and did not shitcan our app -- thanks for your willingness to help.  There's a bug in Facebook and that's what the problem was.